# Finding a series value in a pandas df that includes a date/time field

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df like this:

```
    Date_Time            Time_slot  Veh_ID  Pwr Group_ID
0   2023-03-30 00:00:01          1     100   10    100_1
1   2023-03-30 00:00:01          2     100   12    100_1
2   2023-03-30 00:00:05          1     100    3    100_1
3   2023-03-30 00:00:05          2     100   13    100_1
4   2023-03-30 00:00:22          1     100   22    100_1
5   2023-03-30 00:00:22          2     100   13    100_1
6   2023-03-30 00:00:01          1      55    8     55_1
7   2023-03-30 00:00:01          2      55    2     55_1
8   2023-03-30 00:00:05          1      55   12     55_1
9   2023-03-30 00:00:05          2      55   11     55_1
10  2023-03-30 00:22:00          1     100    7    100_2
11  2023-03-30 00:22:00          2     100    6    100_2
12  2023-03-30 00:25:00          1     100   11    100_2
13  2023-03-30 00:25:00          2     100   14    100_2
14  2023-03-30 00:23:00          1      55    7     55_2
15  2023-03-30 00:23:00          2      55    9     55_2
16  2023-03-30 00:35:00          1      55    9     55_2
17  2023-03-30 00:35:00          2      55   13     55_2
18  2023-03-30 01:35:00          1      55   10     55_2
19  2023-03-30 01:35:00          2      55    9     55_2
```

I need to quickly find the Group_ID that encompasses the date/time and Veh_ID the user specifies. By *encompasses*, I mean the date/time should be within the span of the Group_ID for that Veh_ID: i.e. -- the time should fall in the *start* to *end* range of times for the group that begins with the Veh_ID specified. So

```
def findGroup(date_time, veh):
    ...
    return grpid
```

for

```
findGroup(pd.to_datetime('2023-03-30 00:23:00'),100)
```

returns `100_2`

I could do this with a loop through each group getting the start/stop times and doing a "between" check, but this seems inefficient.

Thx all.

Comment: Could you define what you mean "encompasses" (e.g. does each row define start and stop for each `veh_id`, but then what does `time_slot` mean).  Would be useful to know often are you going to be calling this routine, i.e. some algorithms are better when working in bulk and others are better for one off queries.  Also whether this data can be assumed to be in some state, e.g. are rows sorted in some specific order.  A general routine will always be less efficient, which presumably you care about.

Comment: By encompasses, I mean the date/time should be within the span of the Group_ID for that Veh_ID ... i.e. it should fall in the start to end range of times for the group that starts with the Veh_ID specified.

Comment: @earnric, Could you have different `Veh_ID` for the same `Date_Time` ?

Comment: You only have one date time column, how does that turn into start and end?  Do you mean you start by grouping by vehid and then pull out min and max datetime as start and end, or something else?  Would be good if you filled in your function to show what you mean.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest -- yes, date_time can be repeated for many Veh IDs... i.e. -- the data is for each Vehicle and that data can overlap arbitrarily with other vehicles...

Comment: @SamMason the start and end times are determined by the Group_ID ... each Group_ID has a start/end time-frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, here is a possible solution :

```
def findGroup(date_time, veh):
    gby = df.groupby(["Veh_ID", "Group_ID"])
    ranges = gby["Date_Time"].agg(["min", "max"]).xs(veh)
    m = ranges["min"].le(date_time) & ranges["max"].ge(date_time)
    return ranges.loc[m].index.item() # remove `item()` if multivals
```

Output :

```
findGroup(pd.to_datetime('2023-03-30 00:23:00'), 100) # gives '100_2'
```